# Im not sure if this is a probelm, but the installer is taking a long time without a progress bar and im wonder if it is normal or not

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I'm installing ubuntu on an on an optiplex 7010 with a samsung 840 sata ssd. I am accessing the web browser using the ask a question button and this is my first time installing Linux. I had some issues formatting the drive/root files system, but I got it to the next screen without any errors. It gave a message about partitioning but since there was a continue button and it didn't say it was an error I assumed it was fine and continued installing.

Comment: Ubuntu has various products, and you've not told us which of those you're trying to install. Ubuntu also has used 5 different installers, selected by product/release & ISO used to download, but you've not told us which you're asking about. For 23.04; 4 different installers are available (selected at download by product & ISO you download), but we don't know if that's the release you're asking about, or its another. Please be specific with details.

Comment: Don't install just Linux, try Ubuntu instead, which includes many useful tools, such as the Linux kernel, Grub bootloader, a program to manage partitions and more.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, but i had already fixed the problem. there was a partitioning error that prevented it from downloading. I ended up using linux mint cinnamon instead, since i like the aesthetic more. also, guiverc, the installation was the desktop variant.